# vba excel scrip for attachments failure

Tags: excel, vba, date, pdf, attachment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g8Qb.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTQVk.jpg)I have just tried it with the modified code but unlucky it is still not working. So let me clearify my question further:

I have the pdf file

Risikomanagement-Report Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief 20180706.pdf

in the Folder:

T:\30_Deckungsstock\Deckungsnachweise\tgl.RMR

My aim is to grap this typ of file (with the current date) and attache it to an E-Mail.

My code for this goes as following:

.Attachments.Add "T:\30_Deckungsstock\Deckungsnachweise\tgl.RMR\Risikomanagement-Report Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief" & Format(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"

Issue: It can't find the file. I am pretty sure there is a small bug which I couldnt spot.

The msgbox states: the file cannot be found. Please check the path and the name of the file

Edit: The file exists:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTQVk.jpg)

Comment: Your date format line should be "YYYYMMDD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Attachments.Add "T:\30_Deckungsstock\Deckungsnachweise\tgl.RMR\Risikomanagement-Report Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief " & Format$(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"
```

Note there is a space before the date part.

---

**Edit:**

Use

```
debug.print "T:\30_Deckungsstock\Deckungsnachweise\tgl.RMR\Risikomanagement-Report Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief " & Format(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"
```

to get the filepath being used and verify whether correct.

The current error is because you are not assigning a value to `datDatum` before using it. The default initialized value is being used.

If you don't assign `datDatum` an initial value it will be initialized as `00:00:00`. When you apply the Format function it gets converted to `18991230`

You can verify with the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim datDatum As Date
    MsgBox Format$(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD")
End Sub
```

You will see `18991230` appear.

Solution is to assign a value to `datDatum` e.g.

```
datDatum = Now
```

Comment: Hello vba master, thank you very much for your answeres. I guess my question is really somehow inaccurate. i will try the suggestion by qharr and rephrase the question afterwards if it didnt work out.

Comment: I have just tried it with the modified code but unlucky it is still not working.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I just did. I hope  I am cleaerer this time :-)

Comment: I did: ...Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief " & Format(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf", somehow still not working. It still can't find the file. When I dele the date Format, it works just fine. Thus the issue must lie somewhere with the date comand

Comment: and what happened? We need a description of what happened and any error messages.

Comment: the message is still thesame: run error -2147024984. The file can't be found. please check the file Name and the path

Comment: The file exists: I have just uploaded a pic. below the original question with the Name and the path of the file.

Comment: i use the devug.print function and the reulst is: T:\30_Deckungsstock\Deckungsnachweise\tgl.RMR\Risikomanagement-Report Pfandbrief Hypothekenpfandbrief 18991230.pdf. I guess the date format is wrong

Comment: i have no idea where this value comes from. i have modified the file Name and and replaced the actual date with that value "18991230" and it worked.obviously the code Format(datdatum..) creates specifically that value.I going to do some Research on it. The tip with the debug.print was a great idea. thank you for that

Comment: i define the date as : Dim datDatum As Date

Comment: No worries. Turned out to be something simple in the end :-)